# Beautiful Soup in Python cannot find id despite the id existing

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

the soup.find method returns None instead of the product title despite the productTitle existing in the page.
It works on amazon.it but not on amazon.com

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = r'https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-128GB-Extreme-microSD-Adapter/dp/B07FCMKK5X/ref=sr_1_1?fst=as:off&pf_rd_i=16225007011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=74069509-93ef-4a3c-8dca-a9e3fa773a64&pf_rd_r=HWWSV1CX6VJBC57MRVP6&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1564513802&rnid=16225007011&s=computers-intl-ship&sr=1-1'

    headers = {'User-Agent' : r'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36' }
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    fullprice = soup.find(id='productTitle')
    print(fullprice)
```

Comment: `amazon.com` may use JavaScript to add some elements but BS doesn't run JavaScript. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Comment: There is one difference in pages. The page you are seeing using `inspect element` is not same as returned by `python requests`. `Python requests response` is equivalent to `view-source` of a browser. It means it will contain `initial page` that is sent to user from web server.

Comment: you should check what you have in `page.content` - you will see that there is no expected data.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just need User-Agent header

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-128GB-Extreme-microSD-Adapter/dp/B07FCMKK5X/ref=sr_1_1?fst=as:off&pf_rd_i=16225007011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=74069509-93ef-4a3c-8dca-a9e3fa773a64&pf_rd_r=HWWSV1CX6VJBC57MRVP6&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1564513802&rnid=16225007011&s=computers-intl-ship&sr=1-1', headers = headers)
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('[name="description"]')['content'])
```